# How to attempt inductive proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have got one inductive proof of the F.T.A., as in the image shown below; and am trying to understand the inductive proof based on that. However, there are few issues:

1. Will induction be applicable, as in going from one number ($n=24$) to the next ($n+1=25$), the prime factorization differs totally from $n=24 = 2^3\cdot3$, while $n+1= 5^2$.
2. Why to choose strong induction is not clear, particularly when the earlier number's factorization may have nothing to deal with the next one, as shown in issue (1) above.

I hope that once the above two points are clear, the final(3rd) step of induction will also be made clear.

[image]

Comment: The strong induction part appears when you assume that $n$ is composite: then it is composed of two numbers which are both less than $n$.  If the assumption holds for both of these smaller numbers, then we can rearrange and get the required form of our multiplication for $n$.

Comment: the whole point of using strong induction instead of ordinary induction is that the factorization of $n+1$ will be very different to that of $n$

Comment: Induction in $n\mapsto n+1$ is possible here because we chose strong induction.  Regular induction would not suffice as $(n,n+1)=1$.

Comment: @abiessu Your first comment made the need for strong induction clear, as need smaller factors (any $\gt 1$), which might be rearranged in the new factorization. But, the second comment is unclear. The reason is that comparison is drawn to weak one. Is it that your both comments are two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: $n$ is coprime with $n+1$.  Therefore any assumptions about the prime factorization of $n$ cannot have any affect on the prime factorization of $n+1$ for purposes of this proof.  Therefore, normal induction where we only assume for a single value of $n$ cannot be used.

Comment: @abiessu So, it means there are two different reasons that you have given till now, in your first and second comments respectively. Can I say, they are complementary. First one shows the need of strong induction (& justification for using induction), while second shows the futility of weak one.

Comment: My comments are attempting to address your two separate questions in your post.  “Will induction be applicable?” - yes, the proof is evidence of this.  “Why do we have to use strong induction?” - because weak induction won’t work.